# Simplifying a geometric series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I seem to be completely misunderstanding something about the simplification of a geometric series. $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} ar^j = \sum_{j=0}^n ar^j + (ar^{n+1}-a)$$
Why does this work? From what I tested, it doesn't even seem to make sense when you sub in numbers (when I tried $a=3, r=2, n=5$, the first summation yielded $378$, while the second summation yielded $1323$), so what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I believe that you mean $r^j$ when you have $r^k$; my answer is predicated on this being a typo.

Comment: Indeed it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum on the right side contains terms corresponding to $j = 0, 1, ..., n, n + 1$. We then subtract the term for $j = 0$ and the term for $j = n + 1$, so the terms remaining correspond to indices $j = 1, ..., j = n$; this is exactly what the left side represents.

Comment: I see now, and I see how I misinterpretted it; I interpretted the equivalence as if it were $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} ar^k = \sum_{k=0}^n (ar^k + (ar^{n+1}-a))$$, and not $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} ar^k = \sum_{k=0}^n ar^k + (ar^{n+1}-a)$$That was the problem, thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @user3002473 Yes, that makes a big difference. To clarify, you could write the right side as $$\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{n + 1} ...\right) + (\text{ other terms })$$